# Gemfile use local path in development and Gemfury source in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundler, gem-fury

I am developing both an app and a gem for it. The gem will be available from Gemfury when the app will be in production. But while developing, I would like to use the local path of the gem, so that I can modify both the gem and the app and see changes faster. How can I do this?

I know there is `bundle config local.GEM GEM_PATH`, but this only works for git sources, not for Gemfury.

I can set an env var and conditionally specify gems in the `Gemfile`, but I hope there is a better approach to this.

Answer (score 2):

```
if ENV['RAILS_ENV'] == 'development' 
  gem 'your_gem', path: '/path/to/gem'
else
  gem 'your_gem'
end
```

Then, locally, run

```
RAILS_ENV=development bundle install
```

It's a hack, for sure, but then again, so is all of this :)

Comment: It doesn't work, since in the latest bundler versions you cannot specify a gem more than one time inside a `Gemfile`.

Comment: Ah, you are right!  Sorry about that.  Ok, perhaps try the above.  It's kind of annoying and hack-ish, but it should do the job.

Comment: I will note that I have the same issue as you in one of my projects, and I just find it easier to edit the file manually while I am working locally.

Comment: I can edit it, but it's both cumbersome and error prone, since you might commit the local path with the Gemfile.